# Not printing out all of the statements written

Tags: java

Sample run:

```
License Validator
Enter a last name: ab    bA
Enter a last name: ab bA
Enter year of birth: a12w
Enter year of birth: 1979
Enter driver's license number: A123-4567-9801-23
Consistent
```

My code is:
import java.util.Scanner;
public class five {

```
    private static String getLastName(Scanner sc)
    {
         System.out.println("License Validator");
        System.out.print("enter last name: ab bA");
        String lastname=sc.nextLine().trim();
        if(lastname.length()==0)
            lastname=getLastName(sc);
        int numspaces=0;
        for(int i=0;i<lastname.length();i++)
            {
                if(Character.isSpace(lastname.charAt(i)))
                    {
                        numspaces++;
                    }
                else if(!Character.isLetter(lastname.charAt(i)))
                    {
                        lastname=getLastName(sc);
                    }

                if(numspaces>2)
                    {
                        lastname=getLastName(sc);
                    }      
            }
        return lastname;
    }
    private static boolean Character(char charAt) {
        return false;
    }
    public static String getYearOfBirth(Scanner sc)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter year of birth: 1979");
        String year=sc.nextLine().trim();
        if(year.length()==0)
            year=getYearOfBirth(sc);
        try
        {
        int yearint=Integer.parseInt(year);
            if(yearint<1900||yearint>1999)
            {
                year=getYearOfBirth(sc);
            }  
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            year=getYearOfBirth(sc);
        }
        return year;
    }
    public static String getlicensenumber(Scanner sc)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter driver's license number:");
        String licencenum=sc.nextLine().trim();
        if(licencenum.length()!=17||licencenum.length()==0)
        {
            licencenum=getlicensenumber(sc);
        }
        String arr[]=licencenum.split("-");
        if(arr.length!=4)
        {

            licencenum=getlicensenumber(sc);
        }
        if(Character.isLetter(arr[0].charAt(0)))
        {
            if(Character.isLowerCase(arr[0].charAt(0)))  
            {

                    licencenum=getlicensenumber(sc);
            }
        }
        else
        {

            licencenum=getlicensenumber(sc);
        }
        try
        {
            Long.parseLong(arr[0].substring(1)+arr[1]+arr[2]+arr[3]);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            licencenum=getlicensenumber(sc);
        }
        return licencenum;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String lastname=getLastName(sc);
        String yearOfBirth=getYearOfBirth(sc);
        String licensenumber=getlicensenumber(sc);
        if(licensenumber.substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase(lastname.substring(0, 1))&&(licensenumber.substring(8, 9)+licensenumber.substring(10, 11)).equals(yearOfBirth.substring(2)))
            {
                System.out.println("Consistent");
            }
        else
            System.out.println("fraudulent");
    }

 }
```

It will only output:

```
License Validator
Enter last name:
```

I'm confused as to why the other string methods are not outputting? Also, the if statement for lastName has crossed out the "isSpace" and says that it is depreciated.

Comment: What input have you provided and why are you performing parts of this validation with recursion?

Answer (score 0):

It will only print the prompt for year after you enter the last name  and the prompt for license number after you input the year.

Scanner.nextLine() scans all the user input till he hits enter. So only when you hit enter will it stop reading for input and move on to the next line of code.

And since you have put in validation checks for each input, it will not accept your input till the entered value is valid. Once you enter a valid input and hit enter it will move on to the next method.

**EDIT:**

```
  else if (!Character.isLetter(lastname.charAt(i))) {
            lastname = getLastName(sc);
  }
```

The above part in your code checks if the character is a letter or not and prints the prompt again if it is not a letter/alphabet. So, every time it encounters a space in your last name, it fails the check and prompts you to enter the last name again.

Comment: After imputing a last name in the line "System.out.print("enter last name: ");" , it still only outputs the enter last name line...

Comment: what is that Char method for ?

Comment: @questionsAboutJava Did you use the same input as the sample input above?

Comment: Don't I need the char method to define the lowercase variable?

Comment: you can just use the .toLowerCase method of the String class to convert it into a lower case string.

Comment: I have edited my code but now there is an error with the return last name. It says that there is a syntax error and a byte is expected instead. Why would this happen if I have brackets around my if statements?

Comment: I'm sorry, I changed my if statement to " if(Character.isSpace(lastname.charAt(i)))
                     {
                         numspaces++;                      There is no error code on the return but the "isSpace" part ends up being crossed out and says that the value is depreciated

Comment: I would suggest you edit your question to the new one. I need to see your code before I can tell you what is wrong.

Comment: I have edited my code to show the change. The "isSpace" part has a line through it however in my program for some reason.

Comment: Is it not executing ?

Comment: The isSpace method is deprecated. So Eclipse would show a yellow line over that line of code.

Comment: It is not executing. If I am not supposed to use isSpace method, won't the code continue to not execute the rest of the program (the year of birth and driver's license number)?

Comment: No it shouldnt cause a problem